# How do I get nodes with a specific attribute that contains a colon?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I was looking for a way to find element nodes with a specific attribute and found:
"[Use Nokogiri to get all nodes in an element that contain a specific attribute name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639380/use-nokogiri-to-get-all-nodes-in-an-element-that-contain-a-specific-attribute-na)"

However, it doesnt work when the attribute has a colon, for example "foo:bar" as in

```
<abc foo:bar="hello"></abc>
```

(yes, its valid).

However, when I use:

```
elements = @doc.xpath("//*[@foo:bar]")
```

I get:

```
unexpected ':' after '#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x107458870>' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)
```

And, when I use:

```
elements = @doc.xpath("//*[@foo\\:bar]")
```

I get:

```
Invalid predicate: //*[@foo\:bar] (Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
$ nokogiri -v
# Nokogiri (1.5.6)
--- 
nokogiri: 1.5.6
warnings: []

ruby: 
  version: 1.8.7
  engine: mri
  description: ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
  platform: universal-darwin11.0
libxml: 
  loaded: 2.7.3
  compiled: 2.7.3
  binding: extension
```

Are these old versions?

Comment: What version of Ruby, Nokogiri and LibXML are you using? Type `nokogiri -v` at the command line, and append that information to your question by editing it.

Comment: That's not an attribute with a colon, it's a namespace. If the namespace isn't registered on the root node, you have to register it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It should work. See following example code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/"><abc foo:bar="hello"></abc></root>')
doc.xpath('//*[@foo:bar]')
# => #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x61ca74 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x61c63c name="root" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x61c3e4 name="abc" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x61c36c name="bar" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x61c088 prefix="foo" href="http://www.example.com/"> value="hello">]>]>]>
```

Comment: This only works because you've defined the namespace on the root node. If it was defined elsewhere, the `xpath()` method would have to have namespace information appended.